# Mysterious incompatibility between tally marks and IPA package

Tags: macros, incompatibility, compilation-error, tipa

For a series of lecture notes, I am using a code found in a different trend to make automatic tally marks. The code works fine as long as the package `tipa` is not loaded. Like in the example below

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcounter{TallyCount}

\newcommand{\tally}[1]{%
  \setcounter{TallyCount}{#1}%
  \loop\ifnum\theTallyCount>4\relax
  \StrokeFive\:\addtocounter{TallyCount}{-5}%
  \repeat
  \ifcase\theTallyCount\or\StrokeOne\or\StrokeTwo
         \or\StrokeThree\or\StrokeFour
         \else{Error}\fi\unskip}

%\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\tally{23}

\end{document}
```

However, as soon as I uncomment the package `tipa`, it gives me this error:

```
./Untitled.tex:22: Argument of \addtocounter has an extra }. 
<inserted text>
                  \par l.22 \tally{23}
 
 ?
```

I need to use the tipa package, for I write the pronunciation of some technical words. Is there any chance this can be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tipa` apparently redefines `\:` for its own purposes, you could use `\>` or `\medspace` (which are the same thing)

Comment: as mentioned in the documention one can also load tipa in safe mode `\usepackage[safe]{tipa}` or locally use the command `\tipasafemode` or use instead of `\:`  `\tipamedspace`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer documentation?